# JavaScript library that easily customizes time period and interval in line charts

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, data-analysis, charts

I want to visualize the logs of my website by charts. Here are examples of logs:

```
[{ time: "2017-10-21T13:28:06.419Z", action: "visit" },
 { time: "2013-10-22T13:28:06.419Z", action: "visit" },
 { time: "2013-10-22T13:29:06.419Z", action: "visit" },
 { time: "2013-10-23T13:28:06.419Z", action: "visit" },
 { time: "2013-10-24T13:28:06.419Z", action: "visit" },
 ... ...]
```

Then, I want to make charts like Google Analytics:

[image]

There are two things I want to customize: 1) the start time and the end time in the chart; 2) the interval (by day/week/month). So does anyone know which charting library in JavaScript (eg, D3, highcharts, p5) permits of easily customizing these two things?

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion provides a chart control [ejChart](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/chart/defaultfunctionalities).
Here is a sample that mimics Google Analytics [link](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/sb2jlaeu)

The start time, end time and interval can be customized as needed.

[image: Syncfusion Chart like Google Analytics]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.